# Twitter Authentication OAuth or XAuth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, oauth, xauth

I am trying to integrate Twitter into my application. My basic requirement is to have custom login screen and as twitter requires only OAuth.  As per Twitter documentation I found these

1. [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/)(Downloaded but its missing entire OAuth library, hence could not compile)
2. [bengottlieb](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone)(cannot customize login as it is web based)
3. [XAuthTwitterEngine](http://github.com/aral/XAuthTwitterEngine)
   XAuthTwitterEngine looks promising but XAuth is disabled by default and need permission from Twitter
   So my questions are

1) what type of information I have to provide to Twitter in order to get approval for enabling XAuth

2) if XAuth is not recommended then how do I achieve my basic requirement mentioned about.

i hope my question is valid. Thanks so much.

Comment: what is signature in twitter oauth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also check out my Twitter client. It was specifically written for 'Share on Twitter' functionality. It uses XAuth.

http://github.com/st3fan/iphone-twitter

Comment: thanks St3fan. what info and reason i have to provide to twitter in order to get approval t enable XAuth?

Comment: You have to use the form to request OAuth and then email them to switch it over to XAuth.

Comment: Hello St3fan where i insert Consumer Key & Consumer Secret in my apps?

Comment: @St3fan: which form to request OAuth ?

Answer (score 0):

For future visitor's, here's the link on twitter request form for enabling XAuth, and some more support options:
https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform